# MySQL Create pivot table from existing column in existing table

Tags: mysql

I've got a prexisting table that contains all kinds of customer information. Currently it also has the "city" as well as the "region" and the "state" listed in a 3 columns as strings. Redundant info!

I'd like to create three new tables, one for the city and one for the region and one for the state, that will contain single entries for each of the cities etc, and then reference the ID back into the existing customer table with a location_id.

How would I go about exporting the distinct city names into the cities table, and the distinct regions into a regions table, and then have the cities reference the region_id and state_id table as well so that the information is all grouped!

Amatuer question for sure, but I appreciate any help!

Comment: This is easily achievable via some basic SQL queries.  Have you tried to start this effort and are running into specific problems?

Comment: Also, I might question the need for that level of normalization in this case.  If you are only going to treat the city as a distinct object in your application and the region and state are mere properties of this object, I would only pull the city out into its own table with state and regions as fields.  If of course you will be treating states and regions as first class object entities (i.e. regions and states will have distinct properties), then normalize them.

Comment: Hey thanks man. Yea I'm just... terribly brain dead today it's something awful. I need normalization for the region level as there will be distinct information contained in there as well. I'm anticipating the same for the state level so I suppose it's better safe than sorry?

Comment: Certainly if states and regions will truly have their own properties and business logic associated with them, by all means normalize. I just raised the point, because as originally described these seems like they might just be extra data fields that were only a consequence of the selected city.  Oftentimes you see people "normalize" things like this which just ends up making the application more complex that it needs to be, particularly if you are using some sort of ORM.

Comment: So break the problem down. First step is to extract all city,state, region data from the table.  How do you propose to do that?

Comment: Regions will contain note information, buyers that are associated to that region, products that are associated there, etc... To be honest I'm extremely amateur when it comes to more complicated database stuff, and I appreciate you illuminating some of the downsides to extraneous normalization. I am using an ORM and I certainly don't want things to get too heavy.

Comment: well first I'd group all of the records by the city and then insert those records into a location table... so id get all of the unique city names and their corresponding region and state. then I'd insert back into the main table the corresponding ID's using a join..?

Comment: Sounds like a good start. Though you could opt for SELECT DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY.  `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax would be great here.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I should have it from here. Many thanks I do appreciate you taking the time to assist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want three different tables!  You want one table with three columns:  `city`, `state`, `region`.

The reason is that `city` does not exist by itself.  Consider (in the US) Springfield, IL.  And Springfield, MA.  Or Miami, FL and Miami, OH.  What you have is a dimension of the data that has hierarchies.  The right way to store this is at the lowest level (city in your case) with a "dimension" table providing the other information.

Assuming that your original data is correct, you can do something like this:

```
create table Cities (
    CityId int auto_increment not null primary key,
    City varchar(255),
    State varchar(255),
    Region varchar(255)
);

insert into Cities(City, State, Region)
    select distinct City, State, Region
    from YourTable;
```

I realize that this is not "standard normal form".  But for most applications this works well.  If you are doing this for an application where you want to pick states from a list, for instance, create an index on state and the query will be fast.

There are some circumstances where you might want separate tables at the state and region level.  This would be the case if you had lots of different columns at those levels.  And, in particular, if you were *modifying* the values in those columns.  A flattened dimension (such as described here) is most appropriate when the data is static (cities don't change states very often).  Normalization is most appropriate when you are changing values in the different levels.

Comment: I had the same exact thought as you from the initial problem description - that normalization would be overkill here.  If hoever you look through the subsequent comments, it does seem as if there would be reasonable reason for normalization at least at the region level.

Comment: If I'm changing information regularly contained inside of the region information, however, it would be smart to normalize that column into it's own table as well, correct?

Comment: @Decalmo . . . Yes.  In this case, the need to update would suggest a more normalized approach for that information.  The city and state, though, shouldn't be separated.